# devxpress RepositoryItemLookUpEdit

Tags: c#, sql, devexpress

How to bind devxpress - RepositoryItemLookUpEdit depends on value of another RepositoryItemLookUpEdit in each row
eg.,
consider i have Distance and weight in the first lookupedit. i want to bind the second lookupedit depends on it.

if I'm selecting Distance from first lookupedit then second one want to bind with (Meter, Kilo meter, Mile)
and if i'm selecting weight in first lookupedit then second lookupedit want to bind(Gm, Kg, Ton etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Use `BindingSource`. You can have a master `BindingSource` bound to master table. Then second `BindingSource` bind to master `BindingSource` and as DataMember select a relationship shich leads to detail table. See, for instance, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c12c1kx4.aspx

Or, if you don't use binding, use (selectedindexchanged or something like that) events to set the second combo.

Comment: hi.. these are the repository lookupedit with in the same row.. want to bind the second with respect the first one

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done this before is to use the view's ShownEditor event. With the ShownEditor event you can check to see which colum is the FocusedColumn. If the FocusedColumn is the column that contains the second lookupedit then you can check the value of the first column and either filter the values in the second lookupedit or replace them dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ComboBoxEdit as it would be difficult to bind data runtime to Rep. LU. And for each row ComboBoxEdit you can bind datasource runtime.